# Nested foreach loops within a table to return two lists of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have looked all over and found a number of solutions none of which have given the specific result that I want. I must be missing something obvious!

I am trying to get the list of a users current roles (stored in mysql db) and list show those in the same table as the list of users, below is all I can manage to get to work, a list of all roles that all users are in, not specific to each user. The User to UserRoles is a many-to-many relationship and as such the UseRoles_has_Users table was generated

[Usertable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLORJ.png)

I have created a separate model for the admin index page

Model

```
namespace ComputerAidedDispatch.Models
{
    public class AdminIndex : UserMetaData
    {
        public IEnumerable<User> AdminUsers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<UserRoles_has_Users> AdminUserRoles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
    {
        var users = from u in db.Users
                    select u;

        var userRoles = from r in db.UserRoles_has_Users
                        select r;

        var adminIndex = new AdminIndex();

        adminIndex.AdminUsers = users;
        adminIndex.AdminUserRoles = userRoles;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            adminIndex.AdminUsers = adminIndex.AdminUsers.Where(s => s.username.Contains(searchString));
        }

        return View(adminIndex);
    }
```

View

```
@model ComputerAidedDispatch.Models.AdminIndex

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <p>
        User: @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search!" class="btn btn-default" />
    </p>
    }
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.username)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lastName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.loginAttempts)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.accountBanned)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Roles")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayName("Actions")
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model.AdminUsers.ToArray())
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.username)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.loginAttempts)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.accountBanned)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach(var role in Model.AdminUserRoles)
                {
                    var userRole = role.UserRoles_roleName;
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => userRole)
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.userId }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.userId })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

I feel like the .ToArray() in the line

```
Model.AdminUsers.ToArray()
```

Could be part of the problem, but that stopped me getting the exception

```
MySqlException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.
```

I'm out of ideas so any help or suggestions greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this section of your code in your controller:

```
var users = from u in db.Users
                select u;
```

to be the following:

```
var users = db.Users.Include(u => u.UserRoles_has_Users.Select(s => s.Role)).ToList();
```

Then in your view you can do the following:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.AdminUsers.ToArray())
{
    <tr>
    //... other stuff
    @foreach(var role in item.UserRoles_has_Users)
    {
        var userRole = role.UserRoles_roleName;
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => userRole)
    }
    //.... other stuff
}
```

The key here is that you want to loop over the roles in the `item` not in the `role`.

Note: the names of your properties may vary, if you include your Entity classes I can correct those.

Comment: Wow that's awesome! I knew it'd be something fairly simple. Thanks a lot!